# Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to run a simple spring boot application but it's giving me below error which I am unable to resolve. I am able to connect to database using the same connection string as in `application.properties` file. Please advice

```
C:\Users\shiva\.jdks\jbr-17.0.6\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=51074:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\shiva\Documents\spring-projects\learn\learn\target\classes;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-aop-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.0.8\spring-aop-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.19\aspectjweaver-1.9.19.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\5.0.1\HikariCP-5.0.1.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\6.0.8\spring-jdbc-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.1.7.Final\hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\3.1.0\jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\2.0.1\jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.5.0.Final\jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\6.0.6.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.23\byte-buddy-1.12.23.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\4.0.2\jaxb-runtime-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\4.0.2\jaxb-core-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\angus\angus-activation\2.0.0\angus-activation-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\4.0.2\txw2-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\4.1.1\istack-commons-runtime-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.0\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.10.1\antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\3.0.5\spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\3.0.5\spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\6.0.8\spring-orm-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.0.8\spring-context-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.0.8\spring-tx-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.0.8\spring-beans-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.7\slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\6.0.8\spring-aspects-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-web-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.4.7\logback-classic-1.4.7.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.4.7\logback-core-1.4.7.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.19.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.19.0.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.19.0\log4j-api-2.19.0.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.7\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.7.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.33\snakeyaml-1.33.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-json-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.14.2\jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.14.2\jackson-annotations-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.14.2\jackson-core-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.14.2\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.14.2\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.14.2\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.1.8\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.1.8\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.8.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.1.8\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.0.8\spring-web-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.10.6\micrometer-observation-1.10.6.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.10.6\micrometer-commons-1.10.6.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.0.8\spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.0.8\spring-expression-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\3.0.6\spring-boot-devtools-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.0.6\spring-boot-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.0.6\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.0\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.0.8\spring-core-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.0.8\spring-jcl-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\jdbc\ojdbc8\21.7.0.0\ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar com.shivam.learn.LearnApplication debug

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.6)

2023-05-15T10:43:26.370+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] com.shivam.learn.LearnApplication        : Starting LearnApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 14460 (C:\Users\shiva\Documents\spring-projects\learn\learn\target\classes started by shiva in C:\Users\shiva\Documents\spring-projects\learn\learn)
2023-05-15T10:43:26.374+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] com.shivam.learn.LearnApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-05-15T10:43:26.454+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\shiva\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\jdbc\ojdbc8\21.7.0.0\ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/shiva/.m2/repository/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/21.7.0.0/oraclepki.jar
2023-05-15T10:43:26.456+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-05-15T10:43:26.457+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-05-15T10:43:27.540+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-05-15T10:43:27.569+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 18 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-05-15T10:43:28.533+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-05-15T10:43:28.552+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-05-15T10:43:28.552+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
2023-05-15T10:43:28.644+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-05-15T10:43:28.647+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2186 ms
2023-05-15T10:43:29.061+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-05-15T10:43:29.154+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-05-15T10:43:29.585+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-05-15T10:43:29.591+05:30  WARN 14460 --- [  restartedMain] c.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource    : Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2023-05-15T10:43:30.038+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@2dfdda19
2023-05-15T10:43:30.041+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-05-15T10:43:30.125+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
2023-05-15T10:43:30.841+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-05-15T10:43:30.856+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-15T10:43:30.946+05:30  WARN 14460 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-05-15T10:43:31.607+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-05-15T10:43:31.659+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-05-15T10:43:31.678+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] com.shivam.learn.LearnApplication        : Started LearnApplication in 5.718 seconds (process running for 7.515)
2023-05-15T10:43:31.870+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-05-15T10:43:31.872+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-05-15T10:43:31.907+05:30  WARN 14460 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2023-05-15T10:43:31.910+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-05-15T10:43:31.929+05:30 ERROR 14460 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

2023-05-15T10:43:31.953+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-15T10:43:31.958+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-05-15T10:43:31.979+05:30  INFO 14460 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Below is my `application.properties` file. I changed my computer name few weeks ago due to which I had to update the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora files. After update I am able to connect to database successfully from sql developer and I am using those same connection details in my properties files which resolved the earlier issues related to connecting to database but this new issue I am unable to resolve and did not find much help on google.

```
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=system
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
```

EDIT: When I remove `implements CommandLineRunne`r it starts fine, could you please help me start it with CommandLineRunner so I can learn things by printing on console.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it running by auto wiring annotation context instead of using new operator.